# Test a function on all the values in a list?

Tags: python

I have this list in python:

```
fileTypesToSearch = ['js','css','htm', 'html']
```

and I want to do something like (using pseudo-javascript):

```
if (fileTypesToSearch.some(function(item){ return fileName.endsWith(item); }))
    doStuff();
```

What's the neatest way to do this in python? I can't find a `some` function!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, you might be looking for `any()`, but in this particular case, you only need `str.endswith()`:

```
filename.endswith(('js','css','htm', 'html'))
```

will return `True` if it ends with any of the given extensions.

Comment: Oh, that's really handy on both counts. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this?

```
fileTypesToSearch = ['js', 'css', 'htm', 'html']
if any([fileName.endswith(item) for item in fileTypesToSearch]):
    doStuff()
```

Comment: You don't need the listcomp inside the any.

Answer (score 1):

In general,

```
strings = ['js','css','htms', 'htmls']
if all(s.endswith('s') for s in strings):
    print 'yes'
```

or

```
strings = ['js','css','htm', 'html']
if any(s.endswith('s') for s in strings):
    print 'yes'
```

but see [Sven](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9231494/577088)'s answer in this case.